# How to use a block as method input

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method that uses bubble-sort to sort a small array into numerical order. This method accepts two arguments, an array and a method:

```
def bubble_sort_by(arr)
    while(true)
        counter = 0
        for i in 0...(arr.size-1)
            if yield (arr[i], arr[i+1]) > 0
                saved = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[i+1]
                arr[i+1] = saved
                counter += 1
            end
        end
        if (counter == 0)
            break
        end
    end

    print arr
end

bubble_sort_by([4,3,78,2,0,2]) do |left,right|
    return left - right
end
```

The sorted array should be

```
[0,2,2,3,4,78]
```

Currently I am using Ruby version 2.3.0p0.

I keep getting a syntax error when I try to run this code.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". When asking about a syntax error in your code it *really* helps when you say what it is. That helps us help you.

Comment: I'd like to mention a few things about your code that is unrelated to your question.  1. `loop do` is preferred to the somewhat artificial `while(true)`. For one, [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the `StopInteration` exception, a useful property that you will learn about in time. 2. Iterators with blocks are preferred to `for` loops (which nobody uses): `(arr.size-1).times { |i| ...}`. (cont.)...

Comment: ...3. Ruby allows you to use *parallel assignment* (aka *multiple assignment*) to swap two values of the array without the use of a temporary variable (your `saved`): `arr[i], arr[i+1] =  arr[i+1], arr[i]`. (cont.)...4. Some prefer `break if counter == 0` to your 3-line construct. (Or `break if counter.zero?` to safeguard against the accidental use of a single equals sign.) 5. If the main purpose of a method is to compute a value (here a sorted array), having a print statement within the method makes the method less versatile. Better to move it out and write `puts bubble_sort_by(arr)`.

Comment: ...6. `return left - right` can be shorted to `left - right` since that is the last value calculated before the method returns. Here `return` does no harm, but it's normally omitted when it's not needed. (Of course, `return` may be needed  in some situations where a conditional is involved, such as `return if...`, in a case statement, etc.)

Comment: Thank you all for your input, and thanks Tin Man for the linked article - always good to know how to better ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed version:

```
 def bubble_sort_by(arr)
    while(true)
        counter = 0
        for i in 0...(arr.size-1)
            if yield(arr[i], arr[i+1]) > 0
                saved = arr[i]
                arr[i] = arr[i+1]
                arr[i+1] = saved
                counter += 1
            end
        end
        if (counter == 0)
            break
        end
    end

    print arr
end

bubble_sort_by([4,3,78,2,0,2]) do |left,right|
    left - right
end
```

As you can see, it had two issues:

1. The space a `yield` - basically the space was extra because it wasn't passing the numbers in the parenthesis as arguments;
2. The `return` in the block - you do not want the block to explicitly return the value, you need it to be evaluated in `bubble_sort_by` and then its result used in the context there.